# automatic declaring c types on python variables for cython

Tags: python, code-generation, cython, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to speed up python code via cython. To get an additional speed up I want to automatically declaring C types on python variables.

To do this I want to find assignments like `a = 1.0` ,that try to create integer or float python objects, and than change the code to `cdef double a = 1.0`. (We know that "a" is only used as float. The python code therefore has some restrictions.)

The first task of finding assignments is an easy task with the python ast module. But i don't know how to insert the type definitions. I could modificate the abstract syntax tree (ast) but I assume the cython compiler can't read the changed ast.

Here is my question: Do I need an code generator that allows an transformation from the changed ast to cython code or is there a more natural way for my task (maybe with the help of cython tools)?

Comment: Stefan Behnel from [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cython-users/cltLkB0MQVQ/KbVYtYL-4wIJ): "Cython provides a certain level of type inference, meaning that assignments
of the form "a = 1.0" will automatically be inferred as C double ... Integers are a different beast, because Cython cannot safely restrict the integer range for them. You'll either have to declare them yourself, or use the "infer_types=True" directive in your code, which will enable unsafe type inference."

Answer (score 1):

I think [`Augmenting.pxd`](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html#augmenting-pxd) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can infer types automatically:
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html